# NameError, global not defined when using try,except

Tags: python, exception, tornado, rackspace-cloud

Edit:
Ignore this, I figured it out about 3 seconds after posting this but can't delete it =(

I have this try, except code for working with RackSpace cloudfiles

```
    try:
        cacheobject = cachecontainer.get_object('file.jpg')
    except NoSuchObject as objectname:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)
```

If 'file.jpg' is not found, the exception 'NoSuchObject' is raised. When I run this code I get the error

> except NoSuchObject as objectname:
>   NameError: global name 'NoSuchObject' is not defined

I tried putting NoSuchObject in quotes but then I got an error about string exceptions being depreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**facepalm**

Yeah this programming thing's only my job, nothing big

I have to use the stupid thingy thing don't I

```
try:
    cacheobject = cachecontainer.get_object('file.jpg')
except cloudfiles.errors.NoSuchObject as objectname:
    raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)
```

I'll try and not be stupid in future

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchObject is in another module, probably in cachecontainer.  You have to import it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with an explicit import ? like this :

```
from cloudfiles.errors import NoSuchObject
```