# NameError: global name 'AlreadyExists' is not defined when using try/except within a function

Tags: python

I know many of these questions exist but I can't seem to find one that works for the problem I am having.

I have the following:

```
def function():
  try:
    # function to create a table on hbase
  except AlreadyExists, ae:
    print "WARN: " + ae.message
```

when I call it from another python script it gives me

```
NameError: global name 'AlreadyExists' is not defined
```

...but if I remove the `def function()` and run it on its own, it works and doesn't complain about the global name.

I tried putting `global AlreadyExists` and that didn't work.  I also looked at this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060865/nameerror-global-not-defined-when-using-try-except) but I'm not sure how to apply it because it works on its own (without me having to import anything specific, but as soon as I wrap it in a function it fails).

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you imported AlreadyExists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python only tries to access the name when an exception is thrown. When you ran the code outside of the function it probably didn't throw the exception and that's why you think it worked.

You need to import the AlreadyExists exception from wherever it lives.

Comment: oh ok..makes sense..I thought error codes were thrown by the application and I was catching the name(kind of like printing the name of the error)..didn't realize I had to import the errors I wanted to catch.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
from hbase import ttypes   

...

except AlreadyExists, ae:
```

to

```
except ttypes.AlreadyExists, ae:
```

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/hbase/html/classhbase_1_1ttypes_1_1AlreadyExists.html